# Azure App Service - Detect Shutdown

Tags: node.js, azure

I have a Node.js app hosted as an App Service on Microsoft Azure. Periodically, it shuts down. I'm trying to understand when this occurs. In attempt to do this, I'm sending myself an email on certain events.

Currently, I'm sending an email to myself when the app starts. Then, I try to send an email when the app service stops. I'm attempting this using the following code:

```
const app = require('./app');
const port = 1337;
const server = app.listen(port);

// Respond to the server starting.
server.on('listening', function() {
  sendEmail('App Service - Listening', 'Web site server listening');
});

server.on('close', function() {
  sendEmail('App Service - Closed', 'Web site server closed.');  
});

process.on ('SIGTERM', function() {
  sendEmail('App Service - Exited', 'Process exited (via SIGTERM)');
}); 

process.on ('SIGINT', function() {
  sendEmail('App Service - Exited', 'Process exited (via SIGINT)');
}); 

process.on('exit', function() {
  sendEmail('App Service - Exited', 'Process exited');
});
```

Please assume the `sendEmail` function exists and works. As mentioned, I'm successfully getting an email when the app is listening. However, I never receive one when the app goes to sleep/stops listening.

Am I missing something?

Comment: May be unhandled Exception?

Comment: Is there an event I can tie into to catch that on the app/server level? If so, what is it called?

Comment: Were you ever successful in detecting a shutdown on windows app service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your post code is hosted on Azure Web Apps, you need to modify your `port` to `process.env.port` to make your node.js application run on Azure.

As Azure Web Apps use IIS to handle mapping scripts, and use a pipe port to translate http requests. And Azure Web Apps only expose 80 and 443 port to public.

Meanwhile, you can modify your `prot` to `process.env.port||1337` to make it both run Azure and local.

## update

> **Always On**. By default, web apps are unloaded if they are idle for some period of time. This lets the system conserve resources. In Basic or Standard mode, you can enable **Always On** to keep the app loaded all the time. If your app runs continuous web jobs, you should enable **Always On**, or the web jobs may not run reliably.

You can config this setting on Azure portal:
[image]

refer to https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-configure/ for more.

Comment: I did that. However, I'm still not getting an email when the app goes to sleep.

Comment: Do you get any errors? What mail service you leverage in your application?

Comment: No. I'm just sending an email via `nodemailer` from an old Yahoo email account. Once again, it works during startup. Just when the app goes to sleep or whatever it does on Azure does the email not go out.

Comment: What is the `always on` setting? Is that an Azure Setting or a Node setting? I've never heard of it before

Answer (score 1):

It could be an uncaught exception, try this one to catch them:

```
   process.on('uncaughtException', function(err) {
      console.log(err);
   });
```